# How to generate an inventory report of all AWS Services provisioned after a certain date?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, inventory

I need to generate a report of all AWS Services that were provisioned after a certain date (say last 3 months).

`AWS Service Catalog` seems relevant here; but can this be used only if the services were provisioned using `CloudFormation Templates`?

We did our provisioning using `Terraform` - can AWS Service Catalog still be used to generate an inventory?

If not, is there an alternate way to generate this report?

Comment: AWS Service Catalog is not relevant for your requirement. It is merely a means of providing managed deployments of CloudFormation stacks. It can't tell you about anything it didn't deploy itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the **Resource Groups** for that https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/resource-groups/home?region=eu-central-1#

There you will find the **Tag Editor** https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/resource-groups/tag-editor/find-resources?region=eu-central-1 and list all of your resources.

If you have tagged your resources, you can filter by them. Alternative solution would be to tag all resources with the current date...wait one day...search again and find resources without the specific date tag. So you will find the differences.

To automate this, you can use e.g. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi.html#client

To get a full solution, you can use Tag Editor, get all resources and request the resources itself with the specific API of each resource, e.g. EC2, Lambda, RDS, etc.

This could be time consuming, so maybe a solution like from aquasec could fit your needs.